# Is it possible for a sequence of matrices to have pointwise but not uniform convergence?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, limits, uniform-convergence

Is it possible for a sequence of matrices to have pointwise but no uniform convergence?

The norm for the matrices is the operator norm.

Comment: Your title and the content of the question contradict one another. Which is the actual question?
Edit: Ignore this. Its been fixed

Comment: It should be fixed now.

Comment: In finite dimensions? No. In infinite dimensions? Yes.

Comment: This was exactly what it was about. And what do you mean with infinite dimensions? I.e. what is a matrix in infinite dimensions?

Comment: Recall that a matrix with respect to a basis in finite dimensional spaces has columns given by $Te_1, Te_2, \cdots Te_n$ where $T$ is the linear transformation in question. If you have a linear operator between two spaces where the idea of a basis makes sense (between two Hilbert spaces for example) then you can construct a matrix in a similar way.